# Bottom bar in Jetpack Compose using the onebone Collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to use the [onebone CollapsingToolbar](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar), but also need a bottomBar as used in a Scaffold (see [here](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/scaffold/) for example).

It seems to be possible as stated [here](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar/issues/48), but haven't found any examples or docs on how to go about this. Would anyone know how to do this?

[image]

I'm able to do it with the normal Scaffold, but haven't found a way to do it with onebone.

```
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopNavBar(
                title = header.title,
                navigationIcon = { ToolbarIcon() },
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBar(
                data,
                listener,
            )
        },
        content = {
            contentUi()
        }
    )
```